# Windows Phone DatePicker doesn't update its Value

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, datepicker, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I make a windows phone 7.8 app and i'm using a datepicker.
When i load the page that contains the datepicker, i pass the date and is displayed correctly.My code is:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)

 Dim mydate As String = Nothing
 If NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("date", mydate) Then
   eventdate = Date.Parse(mydate)
   datePicker.Value = eventdate
EndIf

End Sub
```

But when i try to change the date , the datepicker doesn't hold the new date. Does anybody know why?

Comment: How is the date formatted in the string? What culture are you running under? It could be that the standard `Date.Parse` can't recognise it as string.

Comment: It's not that.Even if i set : datePicker.Value=Date.now  to get the current date it does the same thing.

Comment: I'm away from my code at the moment to be sure, but I believe you'll want the `NavigationMode` property of the `e` object. Only set your DatePicker on New navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the way you're not correctly managing the page lifecycle.

When you go to the date selector this is actually a separate page. When tapping the "tick" to confirm the new data selection you'll return to your page. Based on your code above, at this point you'll load the date from the `NavigationContext` again and so the selected date is lost.

The solution is to query the `NavigationEventArgs` and only read the query string when the `NavigationMode` is `New`.

Comment: @JossuaLim Glad you found this answer useful. Etiquette here on SO is to accept (& upvote) useful answers. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask